# Biber in MiKTeX on Ubuntu

Tags: biber, miktex2.9

I installed MiKTeX 2.9 on a fresh Ubuntu 18.04 LTS following the instructions on the MiKTeX homepage: https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx
However it seems that biber is not included in this version of MiKTeX (or I simply did not find it in the package list).
What is the proper way to install biber so that all paths are correct?

Comment: I don't know for Ubuntu, but you may check whether it's installed with MiKTeX Package Manager (via MiKTeX Console) and install it if it's not. Tha Package Manager has a small edit with in which you may filter the list of packages  by a part of the name. Simply enter `biber`.

Comment: @Bernard I did this and for neither `biber` nor `miktex-biber-bin` yields a package.

Comment: this is a long time issue ( https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/2).  the only thing you can do (at least to my knowledge) is either to install biber manually or to use another tex distribution (e.g. texlive)

Comment: @Enno is there any specific reason why you are using miktex and not texlive?

Comment: @samcarter Not a real reason but mainly personal preference. I like the concept of a database of packages with a GUI to install them.

Comment: @Enno Personally I would recommend texlive. From the questions we get on this site, it seems more stable and if you choose a full installation you'll basically don't have to worry again about installing packages and only have to touch it again if you want to update. It even seems to have a gui (https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-50001.3 though I've never tried it myself)

Comment: @samcarter I had a full installation of texlive before and I agree that you never have to care of installing packages. But the gui didn´t work and I couldn´t figure out why. It opened but the buttons had no function.

Answer (score 1):

*Declaration: This is not an answer but can be used merely as a recommendation*

Until now, MikTeX's version for both Linux and OSX does not include `biber` (https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/2). A (the only) workaround is to download and install `biber` manually from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/current/binaries/).

Alternative, Linux users (but also OSX users) are (highly) recommended to install [TeXLive](https://www.tug.org/texlive/). OSX users have also the option to use [MacTeX](https://www.tug.org/mactex/).